# I want to troubleshoot Laravel Livewire on my Xampp

Tags: laravel, xampp, laravel-livewire

I am studying Laravel Livewire, I am trying to get it to run on Xampp by a method without php artisan serve and now I am accessing it using public part and Livewire is not working, how do I solve this problem?
please help me

Comment: "Not working" how? We can't help you if you don't tell us what's wrong

Comment: I'm sorry for asking unclearly.
It doesn't work when the data in the render() function is changed.

Comment: Still not enough to actually help you, you haven't shown any code..